# Protractor: How to access the `ElementFinder` class from within a test

Tags: angularjs, protractor

i'm looking for a way to extend protractor's `ElementFinder` class from within a test. Is there a way to access protractor's ElementFinder class/constructor so i would be able to extend it dynamically from within a test?

A reference of all global variables exposed by protractor would also be very helpfull.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm using below workaround `$('').constructor;` to extend ElementFinder features until [#1102](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/1102).

```
/**
 * Current workaround until https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/1102
 * @type {Function}
 */
var ElementFinder = $('').constructor;

// Examples:

/**
 * Schedules a command to compute the width of this element's
 * bounding box, in pixels.
 * @return {!webdriver.promise.Promise.<number>} A promise that will
 *     be resolved with the element's width as a {@code {number}}.
 */
ElementFinder.prototype.getWidth = function() {
    return this.getSize().then(function(size) {
        return size.width;
    });
};

/**
 * Schedules a command to compute the height of this element's
 * bounding box, in pixels.
 * @return {!webdriver.promise.Promise.<number>} A promise that will
 *     be resolved with the element's height as a {@code {number}}.
 */
ElementFinder.prototype.getHeight = function() {
    return this.getSize().then(function(size) {
        return size.height;
    });
};
```

Comment: FYI, ElementFinder looks to be exposed now: https://github.com/angular/protractor/pull/1633 & https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/1584

Comment: Cool! can you provide all the steps? what to `require` and so on? Can be in a new answer for example ;)